# How to program .emacs file to end up in a specific buffer?

Tags: emacs, startup

I have this code in my `.emacs` file:

```
(load "ielm" nil t)
(switch-to-buffer "*ielm*")
(inferior-emacs-lisp-mode)
(set-buffer-modified-p nil)
```

In emacs 21 and earlier, I ended up with `*ielm*` as the current buffer, but starting with emacs 22 I end up with `*GNU Emacs*` as the current buffer.  What changed in emacs 22 to cause the new behavior, and what can I do to automatically end up in the `*ielm*` buffer?

Comment: Emacs 22 is pretty ancient. The current version is 25.

Comment: Yes, the behavior changed quite a long time ago, but that doesn't answer my question.  My question pertains to emacs version 22 and above, including version 25.

Comment: The question sounds like an archeology problem, tho.

Comment: Stefan, the question was how to achieve in Emacs 22 and above the behavior that I was able to achieve in Emacs 21.  If that is an archaeology problem, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Emacs manual, node [Entering Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Entering-Emacs.html) tells you:

> You can also force Emacs to display a file or directory at startup by
>   setting the variable **`initial-buffer-choice`** to a string naming that
>   file or directory.  The value of `initial-buffer-choice` may also be a
>   function (of no arguments) that should return a buffer which is then
>   displayed.  If `initial-buffer-choice` is non-`nil`, then if you specify
>   any files on the command line, Emacs still visits them, but does not
>   display them initially.

You can find this node in the manual by using `C-h r` (open the manual) followed by `i startup TAB` (search the index for `"startup"`), and choose `startup screen`.  (Other index choices will also take you there.)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, @Drew.
Adding the following to my `.emacs` file gives me the behavior I desire.

```
(if (= (length command-line-args) 1)
    (setq initial-buffer-choice
      (lambda () (get-buffer "*ielm*"))))
```

Comment: You really don't need the if statement. You could just have the setq in your init.  Also, this won't work unless you have already run ielm in your init file because it will only work if the buffer exists and it will only exist if you have called the ielm function. You probably just need to set the initial-buffer-choice to the function ielm.

Comment: Tim X, it appears to me that I really do need the if statement, because if I invoke `emacs foo`, I want just the foo file visible.  Without the if statement, I end up with `*ielm*` in the top window and `foo` in the bottom window.

Comment: Also, I thought it would be too obvious to mention that the buffer needs to exist first, but I guess not.